# Date insert into sfdc in soap integration

Tags: apex, date

I am working on SOAP integration i am getting the date format from third party is

'yyyy-mm-dd'  i want to insert this format into salesforce. my webservice is  accepting  this format 'dd-mm-yyyy'..  how can change my code to  accept 'yyyy-mm-dd' this format i want to store into salesforce i tried like this, below code is accepting  format is'dd-mm-yyyy'...?

```
  String[] str = ocDate.split(' ');
      String[] dts = str[0].split('/');
Date myDate = date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(dts[2]), Integer.valueOf(dts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dts[1]));
  op.CloseDate = myDate;
```

How can i change my code to accept 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

Comment: Sathya please try to avoid using the very general salesforce-crm tag and choose tags which are more closely related to the subject of your question.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke ok sure thanq for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say your current code is actually taking a date of the format mm/dd/yyyy, as you are splitting the string on a slash character ('/') and then passing the third element as the year parameter, the first element as the month parameter and the second element as the day parameter.

To handle a date of the form yyyy-mm-dd you would use:

```
String[] dts = str[0].split('-');

Date myDate = date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(dts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dts[1]), Integer.valueOf(dts[2]));
```

Comment: when i use your code it storing 11/21/2014 like this how can i change 21/11/2014 to store this format.

Comment: That sounds like the date you are receiving is in a different format to the one you specified, and is actually yyyy-dd-mm. Simply replace the swap the first two parameters to the newinstance method: Date myDate = date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(dts[1]), Integer.valueOf(dts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dts[2]));

Comment: when i use above your new code at that time it showing an error System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Close Date: invalid date: Mon Oct 19 00:00:00 GMT 179: [CloseDate]

Comment: That sounds like you are using the american date format then.  The format of the date in the code I posted is correct and the date is being stored as expected, but when it is displayed to you it is in american format which is mm/dd/yyyy.  This is down to your user or org configuration I would say.